# Particles.js works when in .html file but not when in .ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Working on a web development project to learn HTML, CSS, Javascript etc. Using NPM, and Express for my server.js. Im trying to use Particles.js for the background on all of my pages, but it doesn't seem to work when I make the page an .ejs page.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');


const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render("index");
})

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 8081!')
})
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="the-container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <h1>Weather</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="weather.ejs">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a href="indexx.html"> index html</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>

    <script>
      /*particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');*/
      console.log("abc");
    </script>
    <script src="/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

After inspecting the source on the page I found this information:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/particles.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined
    at (index):27

After B. Sommers offered changes to server and index:

```
C:\Users\myName\Development\tester\node_modules\particles.js\particle
s.js:1429
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\Development\tester\node_mo
dules\particles.js\particles.js:1429:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\Development\tester\server.
js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tester@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tester@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.
```

Comment: have you tried exposing node_modules folder?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm new to web development, and honestly don't know what you mean by 'exposing' that folder

Comment: just like how you have done with app.use(express.static('public')); find proper path location where node_modules is so something like app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/node_modules'));

Comment: no change occurs to the error

Answer (score 0):

The `.ejs` file is probably in the folder `views` (but I am not sure as the file structure is not included in your question). Try changing `node_modules/particles.js/particles.js` to `/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js`. If that does not work, try replacing

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      Particles.init({
        selector: '.the-container'
      });
    };

    particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');

  </script> .
```

with `particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');`

Comment: You were correct about my file structure, although neither of those two changes caused particles.js to work, I just have a blank index screen other than the nav.

Comment: In my directory i have server.js, basic.json, package.json, package-lock.json, and two folders "public" and "views". Views contains my ejs files. Public contains another folder, css, which contains my css files

Comment: Try `console.log(particleJS)`

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: No console output, with this .ejs file running:  


    <script src="/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"></script>
    <script>
      particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');
      console.log(particleJS);
    </script>

Comment: Try `console.log("abc")` and see if the javascript is actually being run

Comment: Javascript must not be running, abc didnt print

Comment: Try putting the basic HTML structure in (`DOCTYPE, head, body`)

Comment: I have that, !doctype html, a head importing my css, a body containing everything, no change

Comment: Just did, its up

Comment: Try moving the import of particles.js to beneath the script tag and commenting out `particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');`

Comment: With those exact changes, nothing is being logged still.

Comment: What code are you using to render the file? Is it `res.render("filename")`?

Comment: Check main post, put up server.js

Comment: Removed that asap when i realized xD

Comment: any ideas? the identical code renders particles.js in html but for some reason not through express

Comment: new info B. Sommer

Answer (score 0):

Change your server.js file to:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const particles = require('particles.js');


const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render("index", {
    particlesJS: particles
  });
})

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8081!')
})
```

and your ejs file to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="the-container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <h1>Weather</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="weather.ejs">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a href="indexx.html"> index html</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>

    <script>
      particlesJS = <%= particlesJS %>
      particlesJS.load('the-container','basic.json');
      console.log("abc");
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: btw you've got the api key in there